# Marking read chapters

Tags: epub

I am looking for an ebook-format (preferably epub) and an Android-reader to go with it that marks chapters (or links) in the toc as having been read.

The background is that I have a spider-script that creates an ebook (at the moment plucker) from a weekly magazine.

The structure is simply a table of contents where each entry links to an article.

The thing is now that I don't read this magazine in a linear way, so it is vital for me to remember which articles I've already read.

For the last 5 years (or so) I have been using plucker on a Palm Pilot to do this, but I would like to move to Android, however so far cannot find any reader that offers this feature...

Many thanks for all suggestions.